# Creating Visual Studio Code extension for syntax highlighting of a custom language

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I'm trying to create an extension in Visual Studio Code so as to enable syntax highlighting for a custom language. I found the helpful advice offered by @Wosi here: [Create Custom Language in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687783/create-custom-language-in-visual-studio-code). Based on that I attempted to the following test. I created a subfolder under `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions` with a `package.json` in the root defined as follows (from the above example):

```
{
    "name": "mylang",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": ">=0.9.0-pre.1"
    },
    "publisher": "me",
    "contributes": {
        "languages": [{
            "id": "mylang",
            "aliases": ["MyLang", "mylang"],
            "extensions": [".mylang",".myl"]
        }],
        "grammars": [{
            "language": "mylang",
            "scopeName": "source.mylang",
            "path": "./syntaxes/mylang.tmLanguage"
        }]
    }
}
```

I then created a syntaxes subfolder under that, and included a `mylang.tmLanguage` file based on the example given by @wozi here: [How to create a simple custom language colorization to VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403324/how-to-create-a-simple-custom-language-colorization-to-vs-code) There a couple of minor modifications simply to make the naming consistent with the above JSON file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>scopeName</key>
        <string>source.mylang</string>

        <key>fileTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>mylang</string>
            <string>myl</string>
        </array>

        <key>name</key>
        <string>mylang file</string>

        <key>patterns</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>match</key>
                <string>\b(?i:(hint|info|information))\b</string>
                <key>name</key>

                <string>info-token</string>
            </dict>                
            <dict>
                <key>match</key>
                <string>\b(?i:(warning|warn))\b</string>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>warn-token</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>match</key>
                <string>\b(?i:(Error|Failure|Fail))\b</string>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>error-token</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>match</key>
                <string>\b((0(x|X)[0-9a-fA-F]*)|(([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)|(\.[0-9]+))((e|E)(\+|-)?[0-9]+)?)(L|l|UL|ul|u|U|F|f|ll|LL|ull|ULL)?\b</string>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>constant.numeric</string>
            </dict>                                
        </array>
        <key>uuid</key>
        <string>FF0550E0-3A29-11E3-AA6E-0800200C9A77</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

However, when I open Visual Studio Code (v1.11.2) with the following test file (`test.mylang`):

```
2017-04-17 18:38 Hint This should be blue!
2017-04-17 18:38 Warning This should be amber!
2017-04-17 18:38 Fail This should be red!
```

There are no colours for the keywords (Hint, Warning, Fail). Do I need to do something else to specify a theme? Or do I need to specify a new unique UUID (and if so, can I just make up my own, or do I need to register it somehow)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run the `Developer: Inspect TM scopes` command, you can see that the correct scopes are being used:

[image]

The issue is that there's no color associated with the `info-token` scope in the default theme(s) (hence "No theme selector"). It seems that since [that other answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33413682/2631715), the names of these scopes changed to include a `token.`-prefix with VSCode 1.9.0. This was discussed in [#18839](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18839), and the relevant commit that reintroduced these scopes with new names is [b2aa308](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commit/b2aa308457cdb2bafa61c63712b2f6a4d47362f0).

In VSCode 1.13.0, I get the expected coloring using `token.info-token`, `token.warn-token` and `token.error-token`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, adding the `token.` prefix fixed my problem.